# Query fails with ORA-00904 on Oracle 11 but not on Oracle 19

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle19c, correlated-subquery

Let `p` be a table of master items and for each master item we are to aggregate collection of detail items. Detail items are of two kinds from two different sources. This query fails with `ORA-00904: "P"."NAME" invalid identifier` on Oracle 11 but works correctly on Oracle 19. Why?

```
with people (name) as (
  select 'Alice' from dual union all
  select 'Bob' from dual
), apples (name, title) as (
  select 'Alice', 'apple1' from dual union all
  select 'Bob', 'apple2' from dual union all
  select 'Bob', 'apple3' from dual
), pears (name, title) as (
  select 'Alice', 'pear4' from dual union all
  select 'Alice', 'pear5' from dual union all
  select 'Alice', 'pear6' from dual union all
  select 'Bob', 'pear7' from dual union all
  select 'Bob', 'pear8' from dual
)
select p.name
     , (
         select listagg(u.title) within group (order by null)
         from (
           select x.title from apples x where x.name = p.name
           union
           select x.title from pears  x where x.name = p.name
         ) u
       ) as unioned
from people p;
```

| NAME | UNIONED |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | apple1pear4pear5pear6 |
| Bob | apple2apple3pear7pear8 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gde-GZ4F)

Answer (score 4):

According to [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9531834700346297391) it seems there is a limitation of depth from where the alias of outer table is visible in correlated subquery. This limitation was removed in Oracle12c. For Oracle11g, it is still possible to rewrite query condition so that the `p.name` column is extracted to higher level

```
select p.name
     , (
         select listagg(u.title) within group (order by null)
         from (
           select x.title, x.name from apples x
           union
           select x.title, x.name from pears  x
         ) u
         where u.name = p.name
       ) unioned
from people p;
```

or split union to two parts and combine them later:

```
(with ...)
, parts as (
  select p.name
       , (
           select listagg(x.title) within group (order by null)
           from apples x 
           where x.name = p.name
         ) x
       , (
           select listagg(x.title) within group (order by null)
           from pears x 
           where x.name = p.name
         ) y
  from people p
)
select name, x || y from parts;
```

This was actually my first idea but now it seems the first solution suffices for all cases (at least I cannot think up any counterexample). In real case the aggregation function is `collect` instead of `listagg` so the merge is done using `multiset union` instead of `||`.

---

Also related: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496485/oracle-ora-00904-invalid-identifier)